# Create Dividers in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

If I have a JSON array that looks liket he following..

```
{
"error":false,
"events":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "title":"First entry",
     "date":"2014-11-04"
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "title":"Second entry",
     "date":"2014-11-04"
  },
  {
     "id":3,
     "title":"Third entry",
     "date":"2014-11-05"
  },
  {
     "id":4,
     "title":"Fourth entry",
     "date":"2014-11-06"
  },
  {
     "id":5,
     "title":"Fifth entry",
     "date":"2014-11-06"
  }
 ]
}
```

How do I create date dividers in a repeat so that the DOM looks like such..

2014-11-04 
First Entry 
Second Entry

2014-11-05
    Third Entry

2014-11-06
    Fourth Entry
    Fifth Entry

Comment: Are you just looking to group your data?

Comment: Yes, and no. I want it grouped, which I have done with a sort function. But I also want to display what it is grouped by. Each headers should let the user know which group that the entry is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just group your data in an array.

```
@bindable events = [];
groupedEvents = [];

eventsChanged(newValue) {
  let matchedGroup;
  // clear the array
  this.groupedEvents = this.groupedEvents.splice(0, this.groupedEvents.length)
  newValue.forEach(event => {
    let match = this.groupedEvents.filter(group => {
      return group.name === event.date;
    })[0];
    if (!match) {
      matchedGroup = { name: event.date, events: [] };
      this.groupedEvents.push(matchedGroup);      
    }
    matchedGroup.events.push(event);
  });
}
```

and in your view you can iterate over the groups -

```
<template repeat.for="group of groupedEvents">
  <h1>${group.name}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="event of group.events">${title}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

The JavaScript grouping is mostly plain-old ES6+ code and could probably be a bit more efficient but it should give you a start.

Comment: Brilliant & Elegant :)

Comment: Why do you use splice for clearing the array? (I'm having a few issues and I'm not sure I completely understand what's going on there)

I also had to put 'let matchedGroup' outside of the forEach loop, otherwise with every event it was being cleared and the event wouldn't add to that matchedGroup array.

Comment: I don't think you want to re-assign the value of the array if you can help it so that you don't break any observers.  You are right that the matched group needs to be defined outside of the loop (I never actually tested the code :))